# com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text Data type unable to read in JSP Page

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp, google-app-engine, jstl

I am using hibernate + spring MVC. In My project there is one column in table such as :

```
@Column(name = "CLM_DSCRIPTION")
private Text desc;
```

And getter & setter Method for this

```
    public Text getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(Text desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }
```

now i used this table in jsp where i want to show this column data into table.
M doing as below

```
<c:forEach items="${tbleObjs}" var="tbl" varStatus="status">
  <tr>
    <td>${status.index+1}</td>                              
    <td class="labels2">${tbl.desc}</td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

but it is not geting `${tbl.desc}` here.
 if i did desc.getValue() then it will work but i don't know, which is the best way to achieve this.

Please suggest me a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have achieve with following code :

```
<c:forEach items="${entityObjs}" var="tbl" varStatus="status">
<tr>
  <%
   Entity entityObj = (Entity)pageContext.getAttribute("tbl");
   String disc =  project.getDesc().getValue();
   pageContext.setAttribute("disc",disc);
 %>
  <td>${status.index+1}</td>                                
  <td class="labels2">${disc}</td>
</tr> 
</c:forEach>
```